# Read XML file which contains namespace PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, azure, xpath

All, I am trying to read the `Role` information from `Azure Cloud Service Definition` xml file or`Azure Cloud Service Configure` xml file.

But found `XPath` does't work for them. Both two xml file contain namespace.
By default the namespace doesn't have alias name. and If I add the alias name to it .Visual studio will alert me it is not allowed .

Say your have the Definition like below. and the XmlPath is `/ServiceDefinition/WebRole/@vmsize`. I tested it in a [XPath online tools](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi). and it also can't get the right value for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <WebRole name="test" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpsEndpoint" />
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="HttpEndpoint" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsEndpoint" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="Certificate1" />
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpEndpoint" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="Certificate1" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="LogLevel" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Is there any way to make this XPath work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use the `Select-Xml` cmdlet with the `-XPath` parameter, you also need to specify the namespace. See this article for more information:

http://huddledmasses.org/xpath-and-namespaces-in-powershell/

Here is a complete, working example

```
$XmlDocument = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <WebRole name="test" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpsEndpoint" />
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="HttpEndpoint" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsEndpoint" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="Certificate1" />
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpEndpoint" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
    </Imports>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="Certificate1" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="LogLevel" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
'@;

$XmlNamespace = @{ azure = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition'; };

Select-Xml -Xml $XmlDocument -XPath '/azure:ServiceDefinition/azure:WebRole/@vmsize' -Namespace $XmlNamespace;
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I see. So the issue is my XPath is not correct. Right?

Comment: The XPath had to be slightly modified, yes, but also you have to define the XML namespaces inside of your XML document, in a `HashTable`. That is what I did in the `$XmlNamespace` variable in my example script.

Comment: I also worry about if the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" would be changed after the Azure SDK upgraded. because I don't want to hard-code the XPath. thanks.

Comment: You'll have to change the XML namespace in your script if it changes. I doubt that it will change, however. These things seem to be fairly static.

Comment: If you don't want to hard code the XML namespace, then put it into an external configuration file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I see, I will pass the namespace string to my script through a parameter.